# How can I get the intersection, union, and subset of arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, union, intersection, subset

I want to create different methods for a class called [Multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

I have all the required methods, but I'm unsure of how to write intersection, union, and subset methods.

For intersection and union, my code starts like this:

```
def intersect(var)
  x = Multiset.new
end
```

Here is an example:

```
X = [1, 1, 2, 4]
Y = [1, 2, 2, 2]
```

then the intersection of `X` and `Y` is `[1, 2]`.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#method-M000274

Comment: @Krule's link is broken but I believe he was pointing you to the Array "&" method that does intersection, see some of the answers here.

Comment: That was answered more than 8 years ago. Yes, that was intersection, https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: a is a subset of b if `(a-b).empty?`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Utilizing the fact that you can do set operations on arrays by doing `&`(intersection), `-`(difference), and `|`(union).

Obviously I didn't implement the MultiSet to spec, but this should get you started:

```
class MultiSet
  attr_accessor :set
  def initialize(set)
    @set = set
  end
  # intersection
  def &(other)
    @set & other.set
  end
  # difference
  def -(other)
    @set - other.set
  end
  # union
  def |(other)
    @set | other.set
  end
end

x = MultiSet.new([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6])
y = MultiSet.new([1,3,5,6])

p x - y # [2,2,4]
p x & y # [1,3,5,6]
p x | y # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: 2 big crimes in this answer:
(1) The word `set` as variable name of a plain array; (2) Replicating everything that `Array` already does. 

If the OP wants to add functionality to the `Array` class with some additional methods, you should simply do:

`class MultiSet < Array   def inclusion?(other)   Set.new(self).subset?(Set.new(other))   end   end`

Comment: Agreed... this is probably the most useless class I've seen in my life... but I realize that's not really your fault.

Answer (score 366):

I assume `X` and `Y` are arrays? If so, there's a very simple way to do this:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 4]
y = [1, 2, 2, 2]

# intersection
x & y            # => [1, 2]

# union
x | y            # => [1, 2, 4]

# difference
x - y            # => [4]
```

[Source](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Advanced_Ruby_Arrays#Intersection.2C_Union_and_Difference)

Comment: In other words, just do `Multiset < Array`.

Comment: What if you have 
x = [1,1,2,4]
y = [1,2,2,2]
z = [4]
How can you get it to give you any intersections between with sets instead of the intersection of all sets?
So instead of it giving you [], it gives you [1,2,4]?

Comment: @mharris7190 you can take the union of all those intersections: `(x & y) | (y & z) | (x & z)`

Comment: Don't forget there is also `&=`, `|=`, and `-=` if you also want to immediately store the value like I did! :)

Comment: Exactly what I thought @sawa.  Why is the OP creating this class in the first place?  It doesn't do anything that Array doesn't already do from Ruby's Standard Lib.

Comment: That's funny sawa

Answer (score 19):

If `Multiset` extends from the `Array` class

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 4, 7]
y = [1, 2, 2, 2]
z = [1, 1, 3, 7]
```

## UNION

```
x.union(y)           # => [1, 2, 4, 7]      (ONLY IN RUBY 2.6)
x.union(y, z)        # => [1, 2, 4, 7, 3]   (ONLY IN RUBY 2.6)
x | y                # => [1, 2, 4, 7]
```

## DIFFERENCE

```
x.difference(y)      # => [4, 7] (ONLY IN RUBY 2.6)
x.difference(y, z)   # => [4] (ONLY IN RUBY 2.6)
x - y                # => [4, 7]
```

## INTERSECTION

```
x.intersection(y)    # => [1, 2] (ONLY IN RUBY 2.7)
x & y                # => [1, 2]
```

For more info about the new methods in Ruby 2.6, you can check [this blog post about its new features](http://anamaria.martinezgomez.name/2018/12/21/ruby2_6.html)