# How can I check if another array is a subsequence of the other?

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays; one of them, `b`, is probably a subset of the other, `a`; how can I check if `b` is a subsequence of `a`?

Basically, `[3, 4, 5]` would be a subsequence of `(1..10).to_a`, but not `(1..10).to_a.shuffle`.

Comment: can elements occur multiple times, e.g. `[3, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Shouldn't the last paragraph say `[3, 4, 5] ⊆ (1..10).to_a`?

Comment: @Stefan Depends on what you define equivalence to be; The arrays would have instances of classes that have their equivalence operators overwritten such that it would work well within a hash (i.e., two instances of the same class with the same values would be equal).

Comment: @acsmith probably, fixed.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to check that one array is a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) (specifically, a [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)) of the other, rather than a [subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)? It's just that, since order matters, it sounds like you want a substring, and a lot of the answers you're getting use `sort` because people aren't reading the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @ParthianShot a substring is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Brilliant question !!

Comment: Jeremy, I don't understand the question, which is frustrating, because others appear to comprehend.  How can `[3, 4, 5]` be a substring of `(1..10).to_a` when neither are strings?  Do you mean to apply `to_s` to each and not really mean `substring`, but mean the characters in the first appear in the second, in the same order?

Comment: Updated my answer using each consecutive
    arr = [1,2,3]
    (1..10).to_a.each_cons(arr.size).include? arr

Comment: Why won't you correct the wording of your question?  `[3, 4, 5] would be a substring of (1..10).to_a...` does not make sense, as those two objects are arrays, not strings.  I assume you are aware that a substring is a string.  Also, when I guess what you are looking for, I assume you want all the elements of `a` to appear in `b` in the same order, but I don't know if you mean them to all be adjacent in `b`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland assume that a "string" is just basically an array of characters.  In that context, substring makes sense.  Basically, it would be like trying to find if `[?f, ?o, ?o]` is a substring of `%w(f o o b a r)` or `%w(h e l l o o f)`; the first is true, but the second isn't, even though it contains all the proper characters.  While in this context I would be able to do `to_s` and check, in the original context, I would not.

Comment: OK, now I see what you want, but you still need to edit your question to clarify.  Hundreds, maybe thousands of others may read your question in future.  They shouldn't be required to wade through comments to figure out what you are asking.  Among other things, please avoid the term "substring", as it is not correct.

Comment: @Swoveland Actually, Wikipedia and the rest of the world disagrees: °A string may also denote more general arrays or other sequence (or list) data types and structures.° I'll grant that usage is less common, but it is correct.

Comment: @ParthianShot, what you are really arguing is that use of the term "substring" in this context is not incorrect.  That may be true (but as a Rubiest raised to believe that a string is an instance of the class `String`, I have a problem with that), but it is beside the point.  The relevant question is whether use of the term "substring" made the question clear and unambiguous to all readers, and there is indisputable evidence that it did not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Maybe so. I just didn't think the computer science definition of substring was rare enough to avoid/ And in any case the substitution he used, "subsequence" is too broad a categorization. A substring is a *contiguous* subsequence. Without that modifier, the answers will be incorrect and inefficient. But more broadly, someone else with the same question will find the accepted answer doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but should work for sure.
Simple brute force:

```
def substring?(a, b)
  position = 0
  a.each_with_index do |v, i|
    if v == b[position] and (i + b.size - position) <= a.size
      position += 1
    elsif position == b.size
      return true
    else
      position = 0
    end
  end

  position == b.size
end
```

where *b*  is your array and *a* is a candidate subset.

Comment: `a = [3,4,5]; b = (1..10).to_a; substring?(a,b) #=> false` Or I am missing something?

Comment: My edit switched the parameters around; `a` is the array, and `b` is the substring.

Comment: @JeremyRodi, but why? `a = (1..5).to_a; b = [3,4,5]; substring?(a, b) #=> false`

Comment: while `a.each_cons(b.size).any?{ |c| c == b } #=> true`

Comment: @fl00r, my problem with `each_cons` is that it grabs the next `m` items of the array (`m` being the length of the substring) regardless of whether or not the substring would match that portion.  I believe this code would perform faster, and use less memory.  This is why I accepted this answer.

Comment: @JeremyRodi, No, each_cons won't generate all arrays because it is Enumerator. But yes, it is not as fast as non using Enumerators. But it is idiomatic Ruby. Also Farrukh's solution is not the fastest as well if it is so important for you :).

Comment: @fl00r why not accept JetAbe's answer then?  It does the same thing as yours, except it's even _more_ idiomatic.  Which answer I choose should be the answer I used, and in this case I used this answer, even though both this answer and your answer did correctly answer the question.

Comment: @JeremyRodi it's up to you to choose answer you like, I only don't understand why did you say that my answer was wrong

Comment: @fl00r I can't remember what the first answer was, but I believe that either I didn't read the code correctly, or it was an edit of your answer that didn't do what I wanted it to do

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = (1..10).to_a

a_sorted = a.sort
b.each_cons(a.size).any?{ |c| c.sort == a_sorted }
```

And original solution

```
b.each_cons(a.size).any?{ |c| c == a }
```

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirement of order in this question.

Comment: I say "most likely" because `shuffle` randomly sorts the items of the array; it is possible that `[3,4,5]` would be a *ahem* substring of the array even after randomly sorting it, but it's not very likely.

Comment: I can't sort the arrays, because the arrays were already in a specific order.

Comment: Sort is not mutate original array. I am not sure I understand your pain about sorting here ;)

Comment: I need to check that the specific order is the same; sorting them would change the order, and that's part of what I'm checking.

Comment: Ok, I am confused. What was wrong in original version? `b.each_cons(a.size).any?{ |c| c == a }`. In this case `[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3] != [3,2,1]`

Comment: i think this should stay +1

Comment: I don't see why you have anything other than your "original solution".  btw, it could also be written `([a] & b.each_cons(a.size).to_a).any?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, author said that it was wrong solution ;) "Doesn't meet the requirement of order in this question"

Comment: It's not your problem that the question was muddled.  You made a perfectly reasonable interpretation and gave a good answer for that. Let it stand. Btw, if not obvious, "c" was for "crying".

Answer (score 2):

Using Enumerable each consecutive to iterate

```
arr = [1,2,3]
(1..10).to_a.each_cons(arr.size).include? arr
# => true

arr = [1,3,2]
(1..10).to_a.each_cons(arr.size).include? arr
# => false
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `[1,2,3] == [3,2,1]` is false; if the left side of the union had all of the elements of the right side of the union, then you could drop the right side; so, the second statement, `a.shuffle | b == a`, could be restated as `a.shuffle == a`, which is false in most cases.

Comment: This is a great solution

Comment: `arr=[1,2,4]; [1,2,3,4].each_cons(arr.size).include? arr #=> false`.  I can't tell from the question whether the asker expects that to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: That's true, @fl00r, but you answered 10 minutes earlier.  Don't you mean, "col"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Enumerable's `#find_index` method with each element of the potential subset and ensure that the indices are in the same order in the potential superset.

Try this:

```
a = (1..10).to_a
b = [3,4,5]
# Use #compact to remove all nils
b_indices = b.map {|x| a.find_index(x)}.compact
b_indices == b_indices.sort # use #sort to ensure ordering
```

Comment: Very nice, efficient and reads well, but I'm beginning to think neither of our solutions are for the problem the asker had in mind.  We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple and effective approach (not nil-safe):

```
leftovers = array.reduce(sub) { |a, e| e == a[0] ? a[1..-1] : a }
puts "sub is subsequence of array!" if leftovers.empty?
```

See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Set` or `Array`'s default methods.

For `Array` look at it:
[How can I get the intersection, union, and subset of arrays in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678108/how-can-i-get-the-intersection-union-and-subset-of-arrays-in-ruby)

For `Set`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: `Set`s don't allow values that are equal, and the `Array` question doesn't answer the specifics of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  This solution conforms with my understanding of the problem, but it may not be what the asker had in mind.  See my comments on the question. (Edit: upon clarification of the question, it is not what the asker wanted, but I'll leave it up for its possible educational value.)

**Code**

```
def subsequence?(a,b)
  c = b.map.with_index.to_h.values_at(*a)
  return false if c.any?(&:nil?)
  c == c.sort
end
```

**Examples**

```
subsequence?([3,4,5], (1..10).to_a)         #=> true
subsequence?([3,5,4], (1..10).to_a)         #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], (1..10).to_a.reverse) #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,6])          #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], [3,4,2,5])            #=> true
```

**Explanation**

After computing

```
c = b.map.with_index.to_h.values_at(*a)

c.any?(&:nil?)
```

determines whether `b` contains all the elements of `a`. If it does

```
c == c.sort
```

checks to see if they are in the same order.

*Example 1*

```
a = [3,4,5]
b = (1..10).to_a
```

then

```
d = b.map.with_index.to_h
  #=> {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>4, 6=>5, 7=>6, 8=>7, 9=>8, 10=>9}
c = d.values_at(*a)
  #=> [2, 3, 4]
c.any?(&:nil?)
  #=> false
```

So we see the values of `a` are contained in `b`, we need to see if they are in order:

```
c == c.sort
  #=> [2, 3, 4] == [2, 3, 4]
  #=> true
```

*Example 2*

```
a = [3,5,4]
b = (1..10).to_a
```

then

```
d = b.map.with_index.to_h
  #=> {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>4, 6=>5, 7=>6, 8=>7, 9=>8, 10=>9}
c = d.values_at(*a)
  #=> [2, 4, 3]
c.any?(&:nil?)
  #=> false
```

so again we need to see if they are in order:

```
c == c.sort
  #=> [2, 4, 3] == [2, 3, 4]
  #=> false
```

*Example 3*

```
a = [3,5,4]
b = (1..10).to_a.reverse
```

then

```
d = b.map.with_index.to_h
  #=> {10=>0, 9=>1, 8=>2, 7=>3, 6=>4, 5=>5, 4=>6, 3=>7, 2=>8, 1=>9}
c = d.values_at(*a)
  #=> [7, 5, 6]
c.any?(&:nil?)
  #=> true
c == c.sort
  #=> false
```

*Example 4*

```
a = [3,5,4]
b = [1,2,3,4,6]
```

then

```
d = b.map.with_index.to_h
  #=> {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 6=>4}
c = d.values_at(*a)
  #=> [2, nil, 3]
c.any?(&:nil?) 
  #=> true
```

*Example 5*

```
a = [3,4,5]
b = [3,4,2,5]
```

then

```
d = b.map.with_index.to_h
  #=> {3=>0, 4=>1, 2=>2, 5=>3}
c = d.values_at(*a)
  #=> [0, 1, 3]
c.any?(&:nil?)
  #=> false
c == c.sort
  #=> true
```

**Yet another solution**

```
def subsequence?(a,b)
  ([a] & b.combination(a.size).to_a).any?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One more.  This solution conforms with my understanding of the problem, but it may not be what the asker had in mind.  See my comments on the question. (Edit: upon clarification of the question, it is not what the asker wanted, but I'll leave it up for its possible educational value.)

**Code**

```
def subsequence?(a,b)
  enum_a = a.each
  enum_b = b.each
  loop do
    av = enum_a.next
    loop do
      begin
        bv = enum_b.next
        break if (av == bv)
      rescue StopIteration
        return false
      end
    end  
  end    
  true
end
```

**Examples**

```
subsequence?([3,4,5], (1..10).to_a)         #=> true
subsequence?([3,5,4], (1..10).to_a)         #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], (1..10).to_a.reverse) #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], (1..10).to_a.reverse) #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,6])          #=> false
subsequence?([3,4,5], [3,4,2,5])            #=> true
```